# Detecting and Managing Selected Text

Tags: javascript, css, html, browser, highlight

I'm trying to write JavaScript that manages the text a user selects in a webpage, but I'm not sure where to begin; i.e., I was wondering if there was a way to limit the ability to select/highlight text so that the selection ends at a terminating punctuation mark, and the user cannot select anymore (And possibly trigger an alert window or send an event when that limit is first reached). Also, is there a way to change the colour of highlighted/selected text in a browser? I'm familiar with JavaScript pointer and click events, but I'm having trouble finding any information on what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use css3 to adjust the color and prevent selection on a single element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);`

I found this answer pretty useful when I was looking at that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12823606

The context there is specifically highlighting, but obviously once you have the text you can do other things with it.