# Highlight a text from an Html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

I am totally new to Web Development.  Here, I have an HTML file which I am showing in the `text-angualr`.  Here, I am getting a string which is from the Html file itself like you can say,

```html
<p style="padding:0;color:#000000;font-size:12pt;line-height:1.0;margin-right:0;margin-left:72pt;text-indent:-72pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;;margin-top:0;orphans:2;margin-bottom:0;widows:2;text-align:justify"><span style="vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;;font-weight:700">Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:400;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;;font-style:normal">Developed web app for add management.</span></p>
<span style="vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;;font-weight:700">Contribution:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;;font-weight:400">It was the internal use web app for the <br>we developed the app for the add management for the.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

this is a Html document,which represents it

```
Description:        Developed web app for add management.

Contribution:        It was the internal use web app for the
we developed the app for the add management for the
```

Here, I am able to highlight a single word from this text.  what I want is to highlight a whole text like from `Description to the`, which I am getting as an input.  I tried Different options like,

[How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)

Here From this I am able to highlight a text which is in one tag but what about the remaining text in the next few tags ? I am not able to understand this, can any one please explain me this?  The solution I tried was `3rd` one. I don't have required reputation to put a comment so I am asking this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What part of the mentioned solution didn't you understand?

Comment: You want to stop starting all sentences with Now, makes it hard to read

Comment: Okay I will remove that

Comment: @SoorajChandran In that solution, If  a  there is a span and that span has the whole text which we need to highlight only that will be highlighted and I tried that as well. But half of the text is in first span and half other is in suppose li then it will not highlight the part which is in li and that is required.

Comment: And also It is searching the span tag only, And not the other tags like P

Comment: HI @PeteI have changed the code please look

Comment: @ganeshkaspate textangular is a wysiwyg editor. perhaps what you need is to highlight selected text? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304837/javascript-user-selection-highlighting

Comment: No Not selected text, I already have a text and which is going to be the same text which is in model HTML